# How to set up IPv6 with netplan on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, ipv6, netplan

I purchased a dedicated server installed with Ubuntu 18.04 which was given an IPv6 Block.

[image: IPv6 Block Image]

I used the guide [How to set up IPv6 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://documentation.online.net/en/dedicated-server/network/ipv6/prefix) before.
Since Ubuntu 18.04 uses netplan instead of `/etc/network/interfaces`, the above link does not work anymore.

Yesterday, I set up `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` as following:

```
network:                                                                       
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  eno1:
    dhcp4: yes
    dhcp6: no
    addresses: ['2001:bc8:xxx:100::/56']
```

Things worked pretty well, but today I can no longer ping any IPv6 addresses. Tried in many ways but so far I can have no good result.

I want to know the exact way of implementing IPv6 under this circumstance, how should I do?

Comment: You do not have gateway6 set, so  I guess this would only allow you to ping IPv6 addresses in your local network.

Comment: Yes, but I have not been given the gateway. The original method uses dhclient and duid, which I can't think out how to implement in netplan. Something also confuses me is that why yesterday things just worked and suddenly, everything stopped working. Nothing important changed.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you're turning off dhcp. Maybe you should also turn off accept-ra to configure everything manually.

Comment: You have to use dhclient with the specified DUID with online.net, or the subnet won't be routed to your dedicated server. I'm not sure how you configure this in netplan though. It is probably not possible (yet).

Answer (score 5):

I also have a Dedibox server from Online.net.

After searching the web I find [this](https://twitter.com/nono_io/status/990325983898042368) on twitter

Try the following :

```
network:                                                                       
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  eno1:
    dhcp4: yes
    dhcp6: no
    addresses:
    - 2001:bc8:xxx:100::/56
```

This worked for me and now I'm able to ping6 !

Answer (score 0):

I occur the same issue in another VPS (Vultr), that they suggest me to use "router discovery" to set up IPv6 gateway address.

After spend some time to dig out what's going on, I realize my issue is because I have drop ufw and set up my own iptables & ip6tables firewalls, but have not noticed the difference between IPv4 ICMP & IPv6 ICMP.  So just enable it:

```
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Then reboot.  Afterwards I can `ping6 www.google.com` from my VPS server and get decent results.

Just remember to keep firewall settings after reboot.  For example, if you use `iptables-persistent`, you can use `ip6tables-save` to save them, like this:

```
sudo ip6tables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```